# T-SQL Pivot Error: Incorrect syntax near '0'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my code. I get an error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 82
>   Incorrect syntax near '0'

Can someone help find what my error is? I'm trying to pivot the table so that the query returns Headers with the age groups instead of the rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ID,
         CASE 
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN '0-4 Years'
            WHEN  Age  BETWEEN 5 AND 24 THEN '5-24 Years' 
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49 Years'
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 AND 64 THEN '50-64 Years'
            WHEN Age > 64 THEN '> 64 Years'
        END AS GroupAge
    FROM 
        #AD) t
PIVOT
    (COUNT(ID)
         FOR GroupAge IN 
             (0-4 Years,5-24 Years,25-49 Years,> 64 Years)
    ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused you to need to use square brackets in pivot columns, because of the `0-4 Years` .. columns isn't normal string.

I would use condition aggregate function do pivot.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN  ID END) '0-4 Years', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 5 AND 24  THEN  ID END) '5-24 Years' , 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN  ID END) '25-49 Years', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 50 AND 64 THEN  ID END) '50-64 Years', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  Age > 64 THEN  ID END) '> 64 Years'
FROM #AD
```

Answer (score 4):

Put square brackets [] around your pivoted column names.

```
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(ID)
    FOR GroupAge IN 
    ([0-4 Years],[5-24 Years],[25-49 Years],[50-64 Years],[> 64 Years])
) AS pvt
```